# How to add transition in drop-down menu?

Tags: html, css

```css
.topmenu-header ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.topmenu-header ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 60px 15px 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.topmenu-header ul .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 5s ease 0s;
}

.topmenu-header .dropdown {
  top: 100%;
  left: inherit;
  display: none;
}

.topmenu-header li:hover .dropdown {
  background: pink;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="topmenu-header">
  <ul>
    <li class="top-left-list-border">CATEGORIES
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h3>DONE</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>SPECIALS
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h3>DONE2</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>QUICK LINK</li>
    <li>MANUFACTURES</li>
    <li>INFO</li>
    <li class="top-right-list-border">SHIPPING & RETURNS</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

I am trying to add transition on my dropdown hover. But i can't recognize the right place, as where i have to write the code. I want if i hover the menu. the drop down will come up smoothly. It's a mega drop down and come up at quickly on hover. I just wanna make it a little bit slow. So it look awesome.

Comment: not it's not exactly answer that i need

Answer (score 0):

you mainly need to add transition to your submenu class. I have add the code let me know if you have any confusion

```css
.topmenu-header ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.topmenu-header ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 60px 15px 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.topmenu-header ul .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 5s ease 0s;
}

.sub-menu-parent {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  /* hides sub-menu */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s
}

.sub-menu-parent:focus .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:focus-within .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  /* shows sub-menu */
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
}

.topmenu-header .dropdown {
  top: 100%;
  left: inherit;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="topmenu-header">
  <ul>
    <li class="top-left-list-border">CATEGORIES
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h3>DONE</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu-parent">SPECIALS
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <h3>DONE2</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>QUICK LINK</li>
    <li>MANUFACTURES</li>
    <li>INFO</li>
    <li class="top-right-list-border">SHIPPING & RETURNS</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transition `opacity` while changing `max-height` (but not transitioning that). Please note that I also removed `float: left;` and instead made the `ul` a flex container.

```css
.topmenu-header ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.topmenu-header ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 60px 15px 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.topmenu-header ul .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity .4s ease 0s;
}

.topmenu-header .dropdown {
  left: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
}

.topmenu-header li:hover .dropdown {
  background: pink;
  padding: 16px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="topmenu-header">
  <ul>
    <li class="top-left-list-border">CATEGORIES
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h3>DONE</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>SPECIALS
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h3>DONE2</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>QUICK LINK</li>
    <li>MANUFACTURES</li>
    <li>INFO</li>
    <li class="top-right-list-border">SHIPPING & RETURNS</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all CSS properties can be animated. Here is the [MDN list of properties that can be animated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) - you will see that `display` is not on the list, so animating the change from `display:hidden` to `display:block` cannot be done.

Look through the above list and decide which property you want to animate, and you will be able to create something that works. In the below example, I just picked the height property and you can see that it animates just fine.

```css
.topmenu-header ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.topmenu-header ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 60px 15px 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.topmenu-header ul .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 1.5s ease 0s;
}

.topmenu-header .dropdown {
  top: 100%;
  left: inherit;
  Xdisplay: none;
  height:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.topmenu-header li:hover .dropdown {
  background: pink;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  xdisplay: block;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<header class="topmenu-header">
  <ul>
    <li class="top-left-list-border">CATEGORIES
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h3>DONE</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>SPECIALS
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h3>DONE2</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>QUICK LINK</li>
    <li>MANUFACTURES</li>
    <li>INFO</li>
    <li class="top-right-list-border">SHIPPING & RETURNS</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```